# Is there a way to use baskervald font and old style numbers for whole document?

Tags: fonts, packages, oldstylenums

### Is there a way to use baskervald for *text* and old style *numbers* by default?

I want to avoid customizing each number set. Also I want to have text with proper typography.
I have a complete text of 138 pages in baskerville. When I try to apply old style numbers it changes numbers properly but pages goes up to 142 because of change in typography. What am I doing wrong/missing? Can't get it running without changing text font or size ...

I was trying to use this template as reference: [Utilizing oldstyle figures without resorting to \oldstylenums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums?noredirect=1&lq=1)
, but with no success. And again with another example: [How to make "old-style" the default for numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215260/how-to-make-old-style-the-default-for-numerals). With baskerville it all runs wrong.

I can't find where's the error in my big doc, perhaps order of package call...

My `mwe` looks something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}   % Palatino with pazo math fonts
%\usepackage{cfr-lm} % same result (delivers 140 pages)

\begin{document}
\textit{title}
\cleardoublepage
%content
%\input{138pages}
9876543210

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\end{document}
```

#### Summing up

- *Why* isn't baskerville compatible with old style numbers?
- *How* can I make a clone work properly? Is more than a .sty file required?

---

I assume these links could be relevant but can't figure how/why to put them to use:

- [Which LaTeX fonts have old style numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41095/which-latex-fonts-have-old-style-numbers)
- [Old style number, bold small caps, and Palatino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109956/old-style-number-bold-small-caps-and-palatino)

---

Bottom line problem: the answers are useful to try but I can't quite [move forward](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320844/what-is-happening-with-my-fonts).

Comment: Try it with`\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}`.

Comment: Can you use XeLaTeX and/or LuaLaTeX? There are several good OpenType versions of the Baskerville font family that feature old-style numerals.

Comment: great ideas! I couldn't make them run, neither of suggested options compile the document properly: simply the pdf doesn't appear. (I didn't try LuaLaTeX). @Mico: other solutions/fonts? (although if XeLaTex isn't working I don't know...) `ArashEsbati` 's idea seemed a quite simple one but didn't work. Maybe because I'm using some characters in Cyrllic too? Don't know how to look for the problem.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I couldn't make that one work in a short document. Could you please provide a `mwe`? Numbers don't appear to be set as old style by default.

Comment: @nilon - This works for me `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,proportional]{Baskervaldx}
\begin{document}
9876543210
abcdefgh.  \textsc{Small Caps}
\end{document}`.  Which TeX distro do you have?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I've got TeX Live 2013 (under kile) and your `mwe` compiles a pdf (with pdflatex and xelatex) but with _**no truncated numbers** that go below the line_, nor does the small caps appear proper. This gets weirder every minute.

Comment: @nilon - Maybe you edit your question and provide information like MWE you run plus a picture of the result and relevant excerpt from the log file.

Comment: The console and log files will tell you *exactly* what is going on. There is nothing whatsoever weird here.

Comment: @cfr you're probably right. Just that I haven't yet learned to read the log (yikes!). The console indicates that the font is missing. How is this possible if I placed the .sty file in same folder?

Comment: @nilon Why do you have the `.sty` in the same directory? In any case, the `.sty` isn't the fonts, but just an interface for accessing them, if they are installed correctly. The details depend on the exact error message etc., but you've not said what that is.

Comment: `cfr` and @Mico thanks for comments. They're useful and modified accordingly. I just flagged them to keep everything clean. Yes?

Answer (score 4):

The `baskervald` package lets TeX/LaTeX users access the `Baskervald ADF` font collection (designed by Hirwen Harendal of the Arkandis Digital Foundry (ADF)). According to the package's user guide, "Baskervald ADF is a serif family *with lining figures* designed as a substitute for `Baskerville`. The family currently includes upright and italic or oblique shapes in each of regular, bold and heavy weights. All fonts include the slashed zero and additional non-standard ligatures." [emphasis added] The absence of old-style figures is a deliberate choice of the font designer. Trying to "import" old-style figures from some other, sort-of kind-of compatible font family and match them with Baskerville letters and punctuation symbols should only be contemplated if there's absolutely no better alternative available. (Even then, it should probably be avoided...)

There are quite a few `Baskerville` clone fonts out there, some of higher quality than others. If you're looking for a high-quality `Baskerville` clone that provides old-style figures, lots of glyphs, and upright, italic, bold, and bold-italic shape/weight combinations, you may want to check out the `Baskerville 10 Pro` font family. It's a commercial font -- i.e., it's *not* free-of-charge -- in the OpenType format. To use it in a LaTeX document, you'll need to compile the document with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

The following screenshot shows the font's "regular" and bold weights. There's also a semi-bold weight, in case the bold font weight looks too heavy for your taste.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle]{Baskerville 10 Pro}

\def\test{%
9876543210\par
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäåàèéğłöőøřüß\par
\textsc{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäåàèéğłöőøřü}}
\begin{document}
\obeylines

Regular weight/upright
\test

\medskip
{\itshape Regular weight/italic
\test}

\medskip
{\bfseries Bold weight/upright
\test}

\medskip
{\bfseries\itshape Bold weight/italic
\test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice pointing out the original design intention: _**The absence of old-style figures is a deliberate choice** of the font designer. [Trying to "import" old-style figures] should probably be avoided._ But still: why?

Comment: @nilon - Just for the record: I'm not the designer of this font, and I have no personal knowledge of *why* he (or she?!) chose to provide certain glyphs but not others.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Baskervaldx` as a drop-in replacement for `baskervald`.  From the docs:

> The fonts included in this package are extensions and modifications of
>   regular and bold weights of the baskervald fonts, which serve as a
>   replacement for Baskerville. The changes provide small caps in all
>   four styles, and a total of four ordinary figure types {tabular,
>   proportional}x{lining, oldstyle} in each of those styles.

Borrowing some code from @Mico, here a solution for LuaLaTeX and/or pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fontspec{baskervaldx}
  \defaultfontfeatures+{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}
  \setmainfont{baskervaldx}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[osf,proportional]{Baskervaldx}
\fi

\def\test{%
9876543210\par
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäåàèéğłöőøřüß\par
\textsc{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäåàèéğłöőøřü}}

\begin{document}

\obeylines

Regular weight/upright
\test

\medskip
{\itshape Regular weight/italic
\test}

\medskip
{\bfseries Bold weight/upright
\test}

\medskip
{\bfseries\itshape Bold weight/italic
\test}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @Mico - Outstanding code (+1) should always be recycled `;-)`