# How to use lowercase numbers in-line?

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

I am wondering how you would make use of lowercase numbers in a document? Specifically, are there any packages that introduce these?

Comment: By "lowercase numbers", I think you mean old-style numerals.  If that is so, then this question may help: [How to make “old-style” the default for numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215260/579).  And a search for "old style numerals" on this site will turn up more possibilities.  A more appropriate tag for your question would be "fonts", but I hesitate to change it without being certain what you are looking for; the present tags aren't really useful.

Comment: That is exactly what im looking for, sorry I was unsure of what to tag the question with. I will look into that, thank you

Comment: `\oldstylenums` is mentioned along with a few recent changes at the bottom of page 3 of [LaTeX2e News Issue 31](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf) (the old-style figures are now taken from the TS1 encoding and respect the current font family).

Comment: @bmv see the comment above yours, the 2020 latex release has some additional features here that can not be in that old answer