# How does one make a thousands glyph that scales appropriately?

Tags: symbols, number

James Grimmelman (https://twitter.com/grimmelm/status/1406257482029322250?s=20) posted an idea for a thousands glyph (three vertically stacked sideways zeros).  What would be the best way of creating one that would scale appropriately (observe \small \large, etc)?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\thsnd{%
 \resizebox{!}{1.7ex}{%
   \shortstack{%
      \rotatebox{90}{0}\\[-.2ex]\rotatebox{90}{0}\\[-.2ex]\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}

\begin{document}

1\thsnd  \textbf{2\thsnd}

\large

1\thsnd  \textbf{2\thsnd}


\Huge

1\thsnd  \textbf{2\thsnd}


\small

1\thsnd  \textbf{2\thsnd}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's another solution that uses `\rotatebox` and `\resizebox`, along with `\heightof`, a macro provided by the `calc` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx}
\newcommand{\vthou}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{7}}{%
    \rotatebox{90}{\kern-0.05em000\kern-0.045em}}\kern0.03em}

\begin{document}
\tiny
7\vthou{} \textsf{7\vthou}

\normalsize
7\vthou{} \textsf{7\vthou}

\Huge
7\vthou{} \textsf{7\vthou}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: To add a challenge :), can you make it work with "old-style numbers" (just load the package `\usepackage{cfr-lm}`, taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215260)?

Comment: I tried `\newcommand{\newvthou}[1]{#1\resizebox{!}{\heightof{#1}}{\rotatebox{90}{\kern-0.05em000\kern-0.045em}}\kern0.03em}` but the zeros are smaller tzan the number (`\newvthou{3}`).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - I'm not sure that using oldstyle digits in this context is a good idea (understatement of the month!): the digits have two different heights, and 5 digits have a portion that juts below the baseline, making for 3 separate values of "totalheight". One would thus have to accommodate 3 different heights of the rotated stack of zeroes as well. I am *not* going to go there myself; however, if you feel so inclined, you may want to try changing `\heightof{#1}` to `\totalheightof{#1}` and shifting down the stack of zeroes via a `\raisebox` command.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It was just a weird idea. Again, thanks for replying.